# who wins this game?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Me and my friend are playing  a game. It goes like this;

I pick 29 points on the plane such that, for any three of them, at least two are at most 1cm away from each other. Then the opposite player tries to draw a circle of radius 1 which contains at least 15 of the points. If he succeeds, he wins; otherwise I wins.

Assuming that we both are playing optimally, who wins this game?

How to mathematically solve it?

Comment: Radius of 1... Centimeter? Decimeter? Meter? I presume centimeter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will be the opposite player and win.  First assume that there is some pair of points more than $1$ cm apart.  Considering the sets of three that are these two points plus one other, ever other point must be within $1$ cm of one of the two.  That means all $29$ points are in the area covered by two $1$ cm circles, one centered on each of the first two points.  One of those circles must contain at least $15$ points.

If no pair of points is more than $1$ cm apart, a $1$ cm circle around any one will enclose all $29$ points.

A simple algorithm is then to pick one point and draw a $1$ cm circle.  If it encloses at least $15$ points we win.  Otherwise pick any point outside the circle and draw the circle around it.  The first paragraph will apply because this point is more than $1$ cm from the first point and this circle will include $15$ points.